# Shiny app hangs with a 'please wait' message when loaded on a mobile device (R)

Tags: r, mobile, shiny

I've built a shiny app to load data from Quandl and display graphs that help track my investments. I have published this to shinyapps.io at https://jackpeacock.shinyapps.io/investmentgraphs

This loads fine on a desktop but just hangs at the 'please wait' loading screen on a mobile device. I have tested this with Chrome on a Google Nexus 5 and in Chrome and Safari on an iPad 2. I have also tried requesting the desktop site on both devices with no success. RStudio's website says there shouldn't be issues with mobile devices. (https://www.rstudio.com/faq-items/will-shiny-app-work-properly-mobile-device-iphone-android-ipad-kindle-etc/)

At first I thought this might have something to do with using ggplot2 or quandl packages, but then I noticed I am having the same problem with an extremely simple app I have built previously https://jackpeacock.shinyapps.io/chelseapredictor.

The top of my simpler UI.R document looks like this:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    headerPanel("Can you catch Chelsea?"),
    sidebarPanel(
            dataTableOutput('lTable')
    ),
    mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel("League Predictor",
```

And the top of my simpler server.R document looks like this:

```
# Let's first create the data frame:

Club <- c("Chelsea", "Man City", "Arsenal", "Man Utd", "Liverpool",
      "Spurs", "Southampton", "Stoke", "Swansea", "West Ham",
      "Newcastle", "Crystal Palace", "West Brom", "Everton",
      "Hull", "Sunderland", "Aston Villa", "QPR", "Burnley",
      "Leicester")

Played <- c(27, rep(28, 18), 27)

Points <- c(63, 58, 54, 53, 51, 50, 49, 42, 40, 39, 35, 30, 30, 28,
        27, 26, 25, 22, 22, 18)

leagueTable <- data.frame(Club, Played, Points)

shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {
            output$lTable <- renderDataTable(leagueTable, options=list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
            southampton <- reactive({
```

Does anyone know why I am having problems with mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with capitalisation.

The two links in the above question aren't even loading on a desktop. However, if I use the links https://jackpeacock.shinyapps.io/InvestmentGraphs and https://jackpeacock.shinyapps.io/ChelseaPredictor I no longer have problems on either desktop or mobile.

Comment: You are correct here. This is a known issue on shinyapps.io and it can be a bit confusing: application names on shinyapps.io are case insensitive (two apps can not share the same case-insensitive name), but application URLs are case sensitive.